# Initialize, Start Server and Create Database in Single Script

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, scripting

I am writing a provision script for a dev environment with the following:

```
sudo su - postgres <<EOF
cd ~/data
pg_ctl -D . initdb
pg_ctl -D . -l run.log start
createdb mydb
pg_ctl -D . stop
EOF
```

It fails with the following error:

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Manually executing the commands works. I have noticed that when `createdb` succeeds, there are several `postgres` processes, often 5 or 6, so I added the following:

```
...
pg_ctl -D . -l run.log start
until [ `pgrep -c postgres` -gt 4 ]; do true; done
createdb mydb
...
```

But it hangs, meaning `pgrep` never gets over 5 counts inside the script runtime. I have also tried using a subshell:

```
...
(pg_ctl -D . -l run.log start)
wait
createdb mydb
...
```

With no success.

Comment: Can you try adding the "-w" flag to your `pg_ctl -D . -l run.log start` command, so that `pg_ctl` should only return once the server is up?

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much @JoshKupershmidt. Let me put it in an answer. That is a side effect not documented. Edit: No, actually could you repost it as an answer? So I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the "-w" flag to your `pg_ctl -D . -l run.log start` command, so that `pg_ctl` should only return once the server is up. If that worked, the problem was that your `createdb` command was running too quickly after `pg_ctl`, before Postgres was actually up and accepting connections, when those commands were executed in a script as opposed to manually.

(Re-posting comment as an answer, as requested.)